# Filtering RxJS stream after emission of other observable until timer runs out

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I want to achieve the following behavior in RxJS but could not find a way using the available operators:

- **Stream A**: Generated by a continuous stream of events (e.g. browser scroll)
- **Stream B**: Generated by another arbitrary event (e.g. some kind of user input)
- When **B** emits a value, I want to pause the processing of **A**, until a specified amount of time has passed. All values emitted by A in this timeframe are thrown away.
- When **B** emits another value during this interval, the interval is reset.
- After the interval has passed, the emitted values of **A** are no longer filtered.

```
// Example usage.
streamA$
  .pipe(
    unknownOperator(streamB$, 800),
    tap(val => doSomething(val))
  )
// Output: E.g. [event1, event2, <skips processing because streamB$ emitted>, event10, ...]

// Operator API.
const unknownOperator = (pauseProcessingWhenEmits: Observable<any>, pauseIntervalInMs: number) => ...
```

I thought that [`throttle`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/throttle) could be used for this use case, however it will not let any emission through, until **B** has emitted for the first time (which might be never!).

```
streamA$
  .pipe(
    // If B does not emit, this never lets any emission of A pass through!
    throttle(() => streamB$.pipe(delay(800)), {leading: false}),
    tap(val => doSomething(val))
  )
```

An easy hack would be to e.g. subscribe manually to B, store the timestamp when a value was emitted in the Angular component and then filter until the specified time has passed:
(obviously goes against the side-effect avoidance of a reactive framework)

```
streamB$
  .pipe(
    tap(() => this.timestamp = Date.now())
  ).subscribe()

streamA$
  .pipe(
    filter(() => Date.now() - this.timestamp > 800),
    tap(val => doSomething(val))
  )
```

I wanted to check with the experts here if somebody knows an operator (combination) that does this without introducing side-effects, before I build my own custom operator :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be an approach:

```js
bModified$ = b$.pipe(
  switchMap(
    () => of(null).pipe(
      delay(ms),
      switchMapTo(subject),
      ignoreElements(),
      startWith(null).
    )
  )
)

a$.pipe(
  multicast(
    new Subject(),
    subject => merge(
      subject.pipe(
        takeUntil(bModified$)
      ),
      NEVER,
    )
  ),
  refCount(),
)
```

It may seem that this is not a problem whose solution would necessarily involve **multicasting**, but in the above approach I used a sort of **local multicasting**.

It's not that *expected* multicasting behavior because if you subscribe to `a$` multiple times(let's say N times), the source will be reached `N` times, so the multicasting **does not occur** at that level.

So, let's examine each relevant part:

```js
multicast(
  new Subject(),
  subject => merge(
    subject.pipe(
      takeUntil(bModified$)
    ),
    NEVER,
  )
),
```

The first argument will indicate the type of Subject to be used in order to achieve that **local multicasting**. The second argument is a function, more accurately called a **selector**. Its single argument is the argument specified before(the `Subject` instance). This selector function will be called every time `a$` is being subscribed to.

As we can see from the [**source code**](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/multicast.ts#L54):

```js
selector(subject).subscribe(subscriber).add(source.subscribe(subject));
```

the source is subscribed, with `source.subscribe(subject)`. What's achieved through `selector(subject).subscribe(subscriber)` is a new `subscriber` that will be part of the `Subject`'s observers list(it's always the same `Subject` instance), because `merge` internally subscribes to the provided observables.

We used `merge(..., NEVER)` because, if the subscriber that subscribed to the selector completes, then, next time the `a$` stream becomes active again, the source would have to be resubscribed. By appending `NEVER`, the observable resulted form calling `select(subject)` will **never** complete, because, in order for `merge` to complete, all of its observables have to complete.

`subscribe(subscriber).add(source.subscribe(subject))` creates a connection between `subscribed` and the `Subject`, such that when `subscriber` completes, the `Subject` instance will have its [`unsubscribe` method](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts#L88-L91) called.

So, let's assume we have subscribed to `a$`: `a$.pipe(...).subscribe(mySubscriber)`. The `Subject` instance in use will have one subscriber and if `a$` emits something, `mySubscriber` will receive it(through the subject).

Now let's cover the case when `bModified$` emits

```js
bModified$ = b$.pipe(
  switchMap(
    () => of(null).pipe(
      delay(ms),
      switchMapTo(subject),
      ignoreElements(),
      startWith(null).
    )
  )
)
```

First of all, we're using `switchMap` because one requirement is that when `b$` emits, the timer should reset. But, the way I see this problem, **2 things** have to happen when `b$` emits:

- start a timer (1)
- pause `a$`'s emissions (2)

`(1)` is achieved by using `takeUntil` in the `Subject`'s subscribers. By using `startWith`, `b$` will emit right away, so that `a$`'s emissions are ignored. In the `switchMap`'s inner observable we're using `delay(ms)` to specify how long the timer should take. After it elapses, with the help of `switchMapTo(subject)`, the `Subject` will now get a new subscriber, meaning that `a$`'s emissions will be received by `mySubscriber`(without having to resubscribe to the source). Lastly, `ignoreElements` is used because otherwise when `a$` emits, it would mean that `b$` also emit, which will cause `a$` to be stopped again. What comes after `switchMapTo(subject)` are `a$`'s notifications.

Basically, we're able to achieve the **pausable behavior** this way: when the `Subject` instance as one subscriber(it will have **at most** one in this solution), it is **not paused**. When it has none, it means it is **paused**.

**EDIT**: alternatively, you could have a look at the [`pause` operator](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-etc/blob/main/source/operators/pause.ts) from [`rxjs-etc`](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-etc).